# how can we write a python program to find the average and sum using class object and model by taking user inputs?

Tags: python, class, object, sum, average

I have tried to make class and define its objects to find the sum and average But the code is not working. I have made CricketGame class and create model and objects but code still not working.Can anyone make me more clear about using class object and models.

```
class CricketGame:
    def __init__(self, name, age, matches, innings, runs_scored, wickets_taken, ball_faced, runs_given, ball_bowled):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.matches = matches
        self.innings = innings
        self.runs_scored = runs_scored
        self.wickets_taken = wickets_taken
        self.ball_faced = ball_faced
        self.runs_given = runs_given
        self.ball_bowled = ball_bowled

    def playerstat(self):
        batting_average = self.runs_scored/self.innings
        batting_strike_rate = self.runs_scored/self.ball_faced
        bowling_average = self.ball_bowled/self.wickets_taken
        bowling_strike_rate = self.runs_given/self.wickets_taken

    def playerresult(self, batting_average, batting_strike_rate, bowling_average, bowling_strike_rate):
        print "Batting Average : ", batting_average
        print "Batting Strike Rate : ", batting_strike_rate
        print "Bowling Average : ", bowling_average
        print "Bowling Strike rate : ", bowling_strike_rate

    def playerinfo(self):
        print "Player's Name : ", self.name
        print "Age : ", self.age
        print "Matches : ", self.matches
        print "Inning Played :", self.innings
        print "Run Score : ", self.runs_scored
        print "Wicket Taken :", self.wickets_taken
        print "Ball Faced :", self.ball_faced
        print "Runs Given : ", self.runs_given
        print "Ball Bowled : ", self.ball_bowled


name = raw_input("Enter the name of the player : ")
age = input("Enter the age of the player : ")
matches = input("Enter the number of matches played : ")
innings = input("Enter the innings played : ")
runs_scored = input("Enter total runs scored: ")
wickets_taken = input("Enter the total wickets taken : ")
ball_faced = input("Enter the total number of ball faced : ")
runs_given = input("Enter the total runs given : ")
ball_bowled = input("Enter the total ball bowled : ")

player = CricketGame(name, age, matches, innings, runs_scored, wickets_taken, ball_faced, runs_given, ball_bowled)
player.playerinfo()
player.playerstat()
player.playerresult()
```

Answer (score 1):

playerresult() function requires 4 arguments, you are passing 0 arguments.
When you calculate batting_average in playerstat(), it's not passed to the playerresult() funtion. You can convert those variables into instance variables to access them from another method like this.

```
    def playerstat(self):
        self.batting_average = self.runs_scored/self.innings
        self.batting_strike_rate = self.runs_scored/self.ball_faced
        self.bowling_average = self.ball_bowled/self.wickets_taken
        self.bowling_strike_rate = self.runs_given/self.wickets_taken

    def playerresult(self):
        print "Batting Average : ", self.batting_average
        print "Batting Strike Rate : ", self.batting_strike_rate
        print "Bowling Average : ", self.bowling_average
        print "Bowling Strike rate : ", self.bowling_strike_rate
```

Answer (score 0):

`player.playerstat()` creates and 'forgets' 4 variables because you're not saving them. You can return things you are calculating in `player.playerstat()` and assign it to 4 variables. Then pass those variables as arguments to `player.playerresult()`.

Another way would be to save those 4 variables as attributes of the object (`self.batting_average`, etc.) and change `player.playerresult()` so that it doesn't takes any arguments and instead prints `self.batting_average`, etc.